# Translation of 让日本人打死了 in a text about Japanese occupation

Tags: translation, word-choice

I understand this to mean very clearly "to cause a Japanese person to be killed" or, depending on context "to invite a Japanese person to get killed".

However, the source that I am pulling this from translates it as "being killed by a Japanese person". I am almost certain that this is an error of the text. Am I wrong? Can 让 be used in this way, as if it were 被？

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> translates it as "being killed by a Japanese person". I am almost certain that this is an error of the text. Am I wrong?

Yes, the translation is correct.

> Can 让 be used in this way, as if it were 被？

Yes, in this case 让 is not a verb, but a preposition used like 被 to introduce the doer of the action in a passive sentence. It is used in spoken language. Anyway, there is a difference. While sometimes the doer of the action can be omitted after 被, it can never be omitted after 让. For example:

Correct: 行李**被**淋了。
Wrong: 行李**让**淋了。
Correct: 行李**让**雨给淋了。

Comment: In your third sentence,  行李让雨给淋了, must 让 be followed by 给？ Or would 行李让雨淋了work?

Comment: @BuddyL 给 is used this way (让...给+verb) in passive sentences, but can be omitted. See it as a reminder telling you "this is a passive sentence!" This is useful because sometimes the use of 让 (but also 叫) for passive sentences can cause misunderstanding.

Answer (score -1):

You should first read the full sentence, then judge the meaning of "让". The full sentence should look like:

"XXX **让** 日本人(Japanese)打死了(beating/beaten to death). Note this is equivalent to the sentence - "XXX **is/was** beating/beaten to death **by** Japanese". So, the translation of "让" as "被 (being/been...by)" is correct anf justified.

In order to fit your line of thinking, the sentence should be:

"日本人**让**XXX打死了", which is equivalent to say "A Japanese **is/was** beating/beaten to death **by** XXX".